# NetBeans Project - make project code unreadable

Tags: java, netbeans, hide

I have a java project that I created in the NetBeans IDE version 8.0.1. The project contains a gui which I created with the NetBeans Gui builder, two external API's, and of course some of my personal code. I would like to make this project available to the public, but I don't want someone to be able to just take my project and upload it into an IDE and see all of my work. How do I need to go about making my project codew private and/or inaccessible. All the user should be able to do is run the jar file and use all the functionality of the program. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by "available to the public"? Can't you just make the .jar file available?

Comment: You can use a free **code obfuscator** which shortens names to a couple of random letters and such. And then you might even compile without line numbers and such (javac -g debug options). That would be for sharing the code.

Comment: The code obfuscator was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

By default JAR files are build without sources if you use NetBeans (with its Ant-based build system), Maven or Gradle. It will only contain `*.class` files and resources (text, XML, images and other files).

Of course it is possible to decompile `*.class` files from your JAR. If you want to go an extra step you can obfuscate generate code to make it harder to understand what's going on there.